# Is there a way to filter a set of strings based on whether they appear as part of longer strings?

Tags: r, grepl

I know how to use grepl to see if a list of longer strings contains a list of shorter strings:

```
short <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd")
long <- c("aabb","abbc","abca")
grepl(paste(short, collapse = '|'), long)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But how could I find out whether the list of shorter strings contains **part** of any of the longer strings? Merely reversing the two sets returns 4 FALSE of course, because none of the shorter strings contains the longer strings. In this case my desired output would be:

```
TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Newish to R so no idea if `grepl` is the right solution here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate over your input list:

```
unlist(lapply(short, function (.) any(grepl(., long, fixed = TRUE))))
```

(Or, equivalently, but with named results:)

```
vapply(short, function (.) any(grepl(., long, fixed = TRUE)), logical(1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial matching can be done with `agrep` if we tweak the `max.distance`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(long, function(x) agrepl(x, short, max.distance = 0.3)))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If it is a fixed match, we can do

```
lengths(lapply(short, function(x) regmatches(long, regexpr(x, long)))) > 0
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I don’t *think* OP is looking for an approximate match, they’re looking for a true substring match, but on multiple haystacks.